# Teste Κ de Friedman

Tags: criptografia, matemática

Estou com uma dúvida. Li que o teste Κ de friedman era algo deste género:

O teste Κ de Friedman tenta descobrir qual é o periodo da cifra, calculando diversos valores de Κ(C,C^n)n, em que C^n representa o texto cifrado com n shifts à esquerda, determinando assim o valor mais provável da cifra.

Mas no fundo, o que o Κ faz? sobrepõe os dois textos e vê indices de coincidência? Alguém me pode explicar este método melhor?

Comment: Você tem alguma referência para o material que você consultou, de onde você tirou essas informações? Não entendo exatamente o que está perguntando. De fato, testes estatísticos como esse são usados na criptanálise, mas pra mim pelo menos não faz sentido "tentar descobrir o período de uma cifra" usando dados reais - ao menos quando aplicado na criptografia moderna (na antiga, talvez faça mais sentido, não sei, não sou especialista). Exemplo besta: se você cifrar dados aleatórios, por qualquer algoritmo por pior que seja, o resultado final será aleatório, e não será periódico.

Comment: Pela data (1920), é bem provável que não se aplique ao que chamamos de criptografia hoje :)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher#Friedman_test - Quando se fala em "cifra", é como a "cifra de César", por exemplo.

Comment: uma cifra vigenere por exemplo, nesse link da wikipedia nao entendo bem se é realmente o que eu digo no meu post, é? Trabalha realmente assim ? vê indice de coicidencia de dois textos e calcula vários valores? mas como sabe o periodo da cifra? @Bacco

Comment: Ou seja, sim, se realmente alguém me conseguir resumir en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher#Friedman_test isto de uma maneira mais simples, porque realmente há algo que me está a falhar. @mgibsonbr

Comment: Ah, entendi, na pergunta você não mencionava que se tratava da cifra de Vigenère. Essa sim é uma cifra que eu considero "histórica" - pois nos dias de hoje não oferece nenhuma segurança - e no caso dela faz sim sentido falar em "período". Pois a chave é repetida N vezes e combinada diretamente com o *plaintext*. E de fato dá pra recuperar a chave usando métodos estatísticos (já estudei isso, mas não com o teste de Friedman, usando um método mais simples). Vou dar uma lida nesse material e ver se consigo dar uma resposta.